# taking one element of each type from a list and only taking the first occurrence not working as expected

Tags: javascript, arrays

So this function is supposed to pars an array of object and only take the first occurrence of each type of object there is like 4 different ones and each ones has a dozen of entries.

```
    LastReadingOfEach(measurements){
        let devicesList = []
        devicesList.push(measurements.map((device) => {if (!devicesList.includes(device.Type) ) { return device} else console.log("removed :")}))
        console.log("devicesList : ", devicesList)
    }
```

I created an array and thought I could just push in a device of each type, but I think it doesn't compare against the array as it fill up because it at the end I find the  devicesList  has all elements on measurements

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're looking for can be done with a reducer and findIndex. If find index fails to match the device type it will return -1, we know that we don't have that type yet so it gets pushed into the aggregation.

```js
    LastReadingOfEach(measurements){
        const devicesList = measurements.reduce((agg, device) => {
          if (agg.findIndex(x => x.type === device.type) === -1) { 
            agg.push(device)
          } 
          return agg
        }, [])
        console.log("devicesList : ", devicesList)
    }
```